# Weitzenbock- Anti-selfdual

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, gauge-theory

In "The Theory of Gauge Fields in Four Manifolds", B.Lawson proves the Bochner-Weitzenbock, for an anti-self-dual field $\Psi \in \Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{G}_E)$,where $\mathfrak{G}_E$ is the bundle of Lie algebras associated to an $\mathbb{H}$-line bundle $E$ with connection $A$.

$$d_A^-d_A^* \Psi = \frac{1}{2}\nabla^*\nabla\Psi + \sum_1^4[(R^E_-)_{e_j,.},\Psi_{e_j,.}]+\rho^T(\Psi) $$

where $\rho$ depends on the metric curvature on the base manifold.

Question: Is there a known formula for the $d_A^+d_A^* \Psi$?   (for $\Psi \in \Omega^2_-(\mathfrak{G}_E)$ )